# Apache 2 and .htaccess are downloading, not running, PHP files

Tags: php, apache2

I'm trying to use .htaccess files with PHP on OS X (Snow Leopard, 10.6.8), but when I go to localhost/ the browser just downloads whatever file it's lead to by the rewrite rules (rather than getting the output of the server-side execution of the PHP).

I've confirmed that PHP runs with Apache on other, simpler installations.  For debugging I'm targetting check.php script so that should be good.

The web is full of guidance to hunt down and replace all AllowOverride None statements with AllowOverride All, but my apache configuration for this differs from the base OS X installation and doesn't include any of the various files with the AllowOverride None directives.  I've set all of those touched by my configuration.

This same configuration runs the php scripts just fine when they're hit by the URL.

I've confirmed that mod_rewrite.so is available and loaded.

I'd appreciate help diagnosing / debugging this.

EDIT:
Also, when I hit the page from Firefox, I get a dialog saying "You have chosen to open [blank, for the index url] which is a: application/x-httpd-php5" and the choice to save or run.  That x-httpd-php5 value is the string I use in the AddType directive in the .htaccess file.

Comment: Yeah.  The same http configuration, changing only its DocumentRoot and Directory values to point to a directory holding check.php and no .htaccess, runs the code.

Comment: Permissions and ownership are also the same on the check.php file in both targets directories.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Web Sharing is turned on in the preferences.

Comment: I tried this, but it just starts an "It works" page -- I presume it's running a different http configuration than the one I'm using.

Comment: @chernevik That's a good presumption. Definitely something wrong in your `.htaccess` or folder/file permissions.